# Coded UI Test checking for an open Windows Media Player file

Tags: c#, testing, coded-ui-tests, windows-media-player

I am trying to create a Coded UI property that checks for an open WMP file.

```
   public BrowserWindow VideoWindow
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._videoWindow == null || !this._videoWindow.Exists)
            {
                this._videoWindow = new BrowserWindow();
                this._videoWindow.SearchProperties["Name"] = "Windows Media Player";
                this._videoWindow.SearchProperties["ControlType"] = "Window";
            }

            return this._videoWindow;
        }
    }
```

Obviously, this will not work. Originally, the application opened a link to a video site. So this worked, but since it is quite a bit different than a BrowserWindow I am not sure how to do it. How can I use Coded UI to "grab" it?

Comment: Have you tried looking for it in the proccess.GetProcessByName or GetProccesses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real difference for windows media player from the video site you've been dealing with is that windows media player will be a WpfWindow instead of a BrowserWindow -

```
public WpfWindow VideoWindow
{
    get
    {
        if (this._videoWindow == null || !this._videoWindow.Exists)
        {
            this._videoWindow = new WpfWindow();
            this._videoWindow.SearchProperties["Name"] = "Windows Media Player";
            this._videoWindow.WindowTitles.Add("Windows Media Player");
        }

        return this._videoWindow;
    }
}
```

After that, you just have to get the controls inside of the media player window(WpfControls instead of HtmlControls) to determine which file is open.